# How can I Add newer Data to the start of the xml file (Example inside)

Tags: php, xml

After alot of work i finish to make a xml reader and writer...
but my problem is that i want the newer data that i insert using my form will be added to the top of the xml file.
and not in the bottom..
let me show you an example:
this is the **XML** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events>

<record>
<event>old event</event>
<eventDate>1/1/2009</eventDate>
<desc>old desc</desc>
</record>

<record>
<event>newer event</event>
<eventDate>12/12/2011</eventDate>
<desc>newer desc</desc>
</record>

</events>
```

now..
I want the **XML** file to be like this: **newer data** and then **old data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events>

<record>
<event>newer event</event>
<eventDate>12/12/2011</eventDate>
<desc>newer desc</desc>
</record>

<record>
<event>old event</event>
<eventDate>1/1/2009</eventDate>
<desc>old desc</desc>
</record>

</events>
```

This is my **add.php** (the file that get the **POST** information from the **Form** in the main.html :

```
<?php
$record = array(
 'event' => $_POST['event'],
'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'events.xml' );

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);

$b = $doc->createElement("record");

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
$event->appendChild(
$doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $event );

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
$doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $eventDate );

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
$doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);

$b->appendChild( $desc );
$r->appendChild( $b );

$doc->save("events.xml");

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    
?>
```

**Where do i need to edit to be able to make the **xml*** as i want?*

Comment: Why? Wouldn't it be better to modify your reading code to cope with the events in any order?

Comment: I have a few Iphone application that already read the data from those xml files, so i want to change the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );
```

instead of

```
$r->appendChild( $b );
```

**[Specification: insertBefore()](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore_org.w3c.dom.Node__org.w3c.dom.Node_)**